# How to tell OpenGL to use normals for lighting?

Tags: opengl

Let's say I have

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexbuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*numVertices*3,verticesArr,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,numIndices*sizeof(GLuint)*3,indicesArr,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,normalbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*numVertices*3, normalsArr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24, (void*)(0));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,normalbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,24, (void*)(12));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indexbuffer);
```

is it possible to tell OpenGl to use the normals in buffer for light "calculation"?

Basically I want to know how to say to OpenGl: "Here are my normals take them and make me nice lighting". Since I didn't find answer in google I posted my question here. Thank you for attention.

Comment: Any particular reason for mixing obsolete fixed pipeline with VBOs(modern OpenGL)?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsArr);
```

above code tells OpenGL to consider normals